# Is it possible to enable/disable all breakpoints with project scope only (Visual Studio 2015 and above)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015, breakpoints

Let's say I have a solution with 10 projects, it is an old code base and I am just getting familiar with it. I am doing a lot of debugging and putting breakpoints here and there. I would like to enable or disable all breakpoint in a given project (i.e data access project) but not in all the solution. I want to do this without manually disabling each breakpoint.

Is there a way to do this? If so, which is it? Is there an extension or third party tool that could help me? (I am using resharper but did not find any way to do this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the breakpoint panel, in the toolbar you can click on Columns and check Function. It will add a column with the fully qualified location of the breakpoint (well, up to the function name). Click on the Function header to sort by Function and your breakpoints will be sorted and thus grouped together. You can then shift select the range you want to disable and uncheck one of them, they will all be disabled.

This assumes a somewhat sane naming convention though.

Comment: Thanks! This answer so far gets very close to what I want. I can do this since this does not demmand so much effort. Nevertheless I was looking for a tool to for instance right click a project and select "Disable/Enable all breakpoints" I will mark this as answered if no beter answer is submitted. Thanks a lot

Comment: @taquion, fhl provided the answer for this issue, no other better extension tool, use the default Breakpoint window of VS would be a solution. Of course, I also find one extension tool, maybe it is helpful for you: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioALMRangers.BreakpointGenerator.